# read a numercial number in a string including both numbers and ASCII letters

Tags: matlab

I have the following string including both numbers and ASCII letters, and try to read the last number (the number after the equal sign) in MATLAB without bothering others. How read that number using sscanf?

```
tline = '1,            ,[1024], Application, CBR Server,Total Packets Received = 484'
```

Comment: Do you have to do it using sscanf? Maybe regexp would be better?

Answer (score 0):

If you can live without sscanf, this should do the trick with `regexp`

`t = regexp(tline, '(?<=[=]\s*)(\d*)', 'match');`

`number = str2num(t{1});`